# MySQL Database shows corrupt image unless new record is added

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

So I have a script running that uploads an image to my database along other data. However, there is always one record that has no extension and has the same filename everytime. It doesn't matter if I delete that record, that string of text "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" will populate into another one. It will then transfer to another record if I add a new record.

Here is how I am inserting into the database and into the file system:

```
$art = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_FILES["art"]["name"]));
    $art_ext = pathinfo($art, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(strtoupper($art_ext)=="JPEG"){
        $art_ext = "jpg";
    }
    $art = md5($art).".".$art_ext;
    if($art!=""){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['art']['tmp_name'], "images/".$art );
    }
$sql = "INSERT INTO event (imglink, title, date, tag1, tag2, Price, city, subtitle, venue, password, description, fb) VALUES ('$art','$title','$date','$tag1','$tag2','$price','$city','$subtitle','$venue','$password', '$description', '$fb')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

The image of the records in question are below:
    [image: phpMyAdmin]

Comment: Why are you calling `stripslashes()`? You don't have `magic_quotes` enabled, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` is the md5 for an empty string, so it would seem that your code is reached even when no file is uploaded and therefore with an unset filename/extension

It's hard to tell from the limited code you're posting, but one example how you'd end up with the code called with an empty file name is if the same page is used to display the upload form and accepting the data, and the `GET` falls through to this code by mistake.

Comment: He should check `if ($art != "")` _before_ calling `md5()`.